# Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default, with the function map

Tags: r, dictionary

I don't know why every time after executing Step 2, the error message kept showing:

> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

i have done exactly what the textbook tell me to do. I don't know which value is missing.

thanks for the reply in advance

Here are the codes

```
# Step 1
library(rethinking)
data(Howell1)
d <- Howell1

# Step2
linear_regression <- map(
  alist(
    height ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
    mu <- a + b * log(weight),
    a ~ dnorm(178, 100),
    b ~ dnorm(0, 10),
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)
  ), 
  data = d)

precis(linear_regression)
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on but it sure seems odd that your list mostly uses `~` except for one that uses `<-`. Are you sure that's correct? And are you sure you're supposed to be using `map()`? And not `map2stan()` instead? That code just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for the reply. 
Since we are using stochastic model, we will have to use ~ to represent as distribution. If we use -> it will have a different meaning. One is normal distribution and the other one is the known value

Comment: Just FYI, and for the benefit of others who come later, when I paste your exact code into an R terminal, I get no error; it runs the regression with no issue.  Which is odd to me because I am now getting this same error on other R code (also using the rethinking package), so I would like to know what it means!  But in any case nothing about this code causes it to happen, because I'm not getting it.

Comment: Ok, back again; in my case the problem was that purrr (a part of the tidyverse package) also has a function called "mapper".  This gave me the error  "purrr::map()     masks rethinking::map()", and meant that when I used map() it didn't use the one from the rethinking package, hence the problem in finding the arguments it expected.

Comment: @rossdavidh thank you for the reply. no wonder it continues to show the error. thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error while using `maps` along with `tidyverse` (most probably the reason was `purrr` as part of it, just like it was explained in the comments).

The reason for the error is likely the conflict of packages that have functions with similar names. One can avoid it by specifying the source package for the function, i.e. typing things like

```
maps::map()
```

for `map()` function.

If you have to type this command many times, you might want to look at `conflicted` package instead. It provides the command `conflict_prefer()` that you can use by placing a line like this at the top of your script:

```
conflict_prefer("map", "maps")
```